# How to parse JSON into a single nested object with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with jq but I can't get it right. How do I parse the following JSON to:

- A single nested object and also add additional top level keys ("cities", "uppsala", and "locations" in the example)
- Use the values for the keys `name` as keys for the objects?

(shortened version of source json):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Uppsala domkyrka"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          17.6336159,
          59.8581466
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Uppsala moské"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          17.6382165,
          59.874003
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**I'm trying to parse it to this format**:

```
{
  "cities": {
    "uppsala": {
      "locations": {
        "Uppsala domkyrka": {
          "name": "Uppsala domkyrka",
          "coordinates": {
            "_latitude": 59.854,
            "_longitude": 17.6261
          }
        },
        "Uppsala moské": {
          "name": "Uppsala moské",
          "coordinates": {
            "_latitude": 59.8581,
            "_longitude": 17.6336
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the command I've arrived at so far:

```
[.features[] | {name: .properties.name, coordinates: {_latitude: .geometry.coordinates[0], _longitude: .geometry.coordinates[1]}}]
```

To produce this, which is not quite right:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Uppsala domkyrka",
    "coordinates": {
      "_latitude": 17.6336159,
      "_longitude": 59.8581466
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Uppsala moské",
    "coordinates": {
      "_latitude": 17.6382165,
      "_longitude": 59.874003
    }
  }
]
```

I haven't managed to get the values for `name` as keys for the objects.

Any ideas? I've been reading SO for hours and pulling my hair out..

Comment: Your expected output isn't a valid JSON, you can't have duplicate keys of same name `ID`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out promptly @Inian and @ peak - clearly a misunderstanding on my part. I believe it's corrected, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to hard-code the three top-most keys, the key to a solution is `add`:

```
{
  "cities": {
    "uppsala": {
      "locations":
        [.features[]
         | {name: .properties.name,
            coordinates:
              {_latitude: .geometry.coordinates[0],
               _longitude: .geometry.coordinates[1]
              }
            }
         | {(.name): .}
        ] | add
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want the redundancy of the `name`, you could replace `{(.name): .}` with:

```
{(.name): del(.name)}
```

### A more compact variant

The critical `add` gets a bit lost in the above, so you might like to consider this equivalent alternative:

```
[.features[]
 | {name: .properties.name,
    coordinates:
      { _latitude: .geometry.coordinates[0],
        _longitude: .geometry.coordinates[1]
      }
   } | {(.name): .} ]
| add as $v
| ({} | .cities.uppsala.locations = $v)
```